# NEO4J Cypher - filtering path variables

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following query returns a path, the goal is to filter the results by the date on the `acted_in` relationship:

```
MATCH path = ((n:actor)-[t:acted_in]->(g:movie)-[k:won_award]->(i:award)) 
WHERE n.actor_name="John" AND g.movie="Some Movie" AND i.award="Best Movie"
AND '2019-11-22T13:12:51+00:00' <= t.date <= '2019-11-22T14:13:53+00:00' and '2019-11-22T13:12:51+00:00' <= k.date <= '2019-11-22T14:13:53+00:00' 
RETURN nodes(path), relationships(path)
```

But it seems that the filtering by date has no effect when returning a path variable - it returns **ALL** the paths between the two nodes.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific with the issue? Can you provide details on an example case that shows the problem?

Comment: Is this in the Neo4j Browser?

Comment: Thanks guys, in the end I used temporals: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/ instead of strings and that worked for me.